# (Java) Graphics change resolution?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, screen-resolution

I'm drawing to a `Canvas` using `Graphics` through a `BufferStrategy` with lines such as

```
g.drawImage(bufferedImage, x, y, null);
```

I currently have this running undecorated in a `JFrame`, 1920x1080p as per the resolution of my laptop. I'm curious as to whether there is any way to alter the resolution of the `Graphics` rendered, particularly lowering resolution so as to increase efficiency/speed, or fitting to another differently sized screen. There are many objects being rendered with a camera and the game runs fairly well, but any usable alterations to the resolution would be useful as optional in my settings.

I've researched this and found no good answers. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Resolution changes such as for printing.)

Best to use a drawImage with a smaller image, and scaled width and height.

Now, you could even render all in your own BufferedImage using a Graphics2D with BufferedImage.createGraphics and scale afterwards. Not so nice for text or printing.

Or use Graphics2D scaling:

For complex rendering:

```
g.scale(2.0, 2.0);
... // Draw smaller image
g.scale(0.5, 0.5);
```

As you might imagine this probably does not help in memory consumption, apart from needing smaller images. At one point all pixels of the image must be given in the devices color size. 256 colors gif, or 10KB jpg will not help.

The other way around, supporting high resolutions with tight memory also exists. There one might use **tiled images**, see `ImageIO`.

Important is to prepare the image outside the `paintComponent`/`paint`.

You might also go for device compatible bit maps if you make your own BufferedImage, but this seems circumstantial (GraphicsEnvironment).